# Swift scrollview adding from XIB not scrollable at all

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xib

I'm trying to import from Xib full screen ScrollView into my ViewController.

Following that [guide](https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7) i've made many working examples of it, but when importing it from Xib, ScrollView not responding on scroll (not even bouncing)

My Xib View class:

```
class TestScroll: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

public static func getViewFromNib() -> TestScroll {
    return UINib(nibName: "TestScroll", bundle: .main).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! TestScroll
    }
}
```

And this is how i adding it in ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let testScroll = TestScroll.getViewFromNib()
    self.view.addSubview(testScroll)
}
```

Please help, i've checked many guides already, but not found working example with Xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a frame / constraints

```
let testScroll = TestScroll.getViewFromNib()
testScroll.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(testScroll)
```

leave this

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

only if you'll set constraints